# Can't use es6 modules with webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I get error when trying to use es6 modules with babel loader in webpack. It works fine with require, but not with import.

if I do:

```
foo = require( './app/data.js'); //it works
```

but

```
import foo from './app/data.js'; //gives me a syntax error:
```

`: Module parse failed Line 1: Unexpected token 
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

```
loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      },
```

paths:

webpackconfig
/app/main.js

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.1.20",
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "less": "^2.5.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.10.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.1.19"
  }
```

Comment: Please read tag descriptions. `babel` is for questions for a *Python library* with said name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like babel is not taken part on the party. Things to check regarding the file containing the `import foo from 'data';` statement:

1. Check that the file is under the `src` directory.
2. Check that the file extension is `.js`.

As a side note... the ES6 equivalent to:

```
foo = require( './data');
```

would be,

```
import foo from './data';
                 ^^
```

Comment: thanks, I forgot to change the src path in the webpack conifg